# Firefox error - Unable to establish connection to WebSocket server

Tags: python, node.js, ssl, firefox, websocket

I'm trying to run a WebSocket demo using a client-side HTML file and a Python server script over HTTPS. However, when I load the HTML file in Firefox, I encounter an error stating "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:8000/."

```html
socket_client.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: "Courier New", sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .buttons {
                font-size: 4em;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .button, .value {
                line-height: 1;
                padding: 2rem;
                margin: 2rem;
                border: medium solid;
                min-height: 1em;
                min-width: 1em;
            }
            .button {
                cursor: pointer;
                user-select: none;
            }
            .minus {
                color: red;
            }
            .plus {
                color: green;
            }
            .value {
                min-width: 2em;
            }
            .state {
                font-size: 2em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="minus button">-</div>
            <div class="value">?</div>
            <div class="plus button">+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="state">
            <span class="users">?</span> online
        </div>
        <script>
            var minus = document.querySelector('.minus'),
                plus = document.querySelector('.plus'),
                value = document.querySelector('.value'),
                users = document.querySelector('.users'),
                websocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8000/");
            minus.onclick = function (event) {
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify({action: 'minus'}));
            }
            plus.onclick = function (event) {
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify({action: 'plus'}));
            }
            websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
                data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                switch (data.type) {
                    case 'state':
                        value.textContent = data.value;
                        break;
                    case 'users':
                        users.textContent = (
                            data.count.toString() + " user" +
                            (data.count == 1 ? "" : "s"));
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.error(
                            "unsupported event", data);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```py
server.py
# WS server example that synchronizes state across clients

import asyncio
import json
import logging
import websockets
import ssl

logging.basicConfig()

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)

# Generate with Lets Encrypt, chown to current user and 400 permissions
ssl_cert = "cert.pem"
ssl_key = "key.pem"

ssl_context.load_cert_chain(ssl_cert, keyfile=ssl_key)

STATE = {"value": 0}

USERS = set()


def state_event():
    return json.dumps({"type": "state", **STATE})


def users_event():
    return json.dumps({"type": "users", "count": len(USERS)})


async def notify_state():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = state_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def notify_users():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = users_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def register(websocket):
    USERS.add(websocket)
    await notify_users()


async def unregister(websocket):
    USERS.remove(websocket)
    await notify_users()


async def counter(websocket, path):
    # register(websocket) sends user_event() to websocket
    await register(websocket)
    try:
        await websocket.send(state_event())
        async for message in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data["action"] == "minus":
                STATE["value"] -= 1
                await notify_state()
            elif data["action"] == "plus":
                STATE["value"] += 1
                await notify_state()
            else:
                logging.error("unsupported event: {}", data)
    finally:
        await unregister(websocket)


start_server = websockets.serve(counter, "0.0.0.0", 8000, ssl=ssl_context)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**Error:**
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:8000/.

I have a client-side HTML file named `socket_client.html`, which contains JavaScript code to establish a WebSocket connection. The server-side code is implemented in Python using the `websockets` library. The server is configured to use SSL/TLS encryption with a self-signed certificate.

When I open the `socket_client.html` file in Firefox, it fails to establish a connection to the WebSocket server at `wss://localhost:8000/`. The error message provided by Firefox states "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:8000/".

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect the WebSocket client to successfully establish a connection with the WebSocket server running on `localhost` at port `8000` and be able to send and receive messages.

**Additional Information:**

- The `socket_client.html` file contains JavaScript code to handle button clicks and send WebSocket messages based on the clicked button.
- The `server.py` script sets up the WebSocket server using `websockets` and implements functionality to synchronize state across clients.
- The server uses SSL/TLS encryption with a self-signed certificate (`cert.pem` and `key.pem`) generated using Let's Encrypt. The permissions for the certificate files have been set correctly.
- I have confirmed that the server script is running and listening on `0.0.0.0:8000` as intended.

**Question:**
What could be causing this error in Firefox, and how can I resolve it? Is there any specific configuration or setting that needs to be adjusted in Firefox to establish a WebSocket connection with a server using a self-signed certificate?